# Rotating a pinhole camera in 3D

Tags: c++, raytracing, rotational-matrices

I am trying to rotate a pinhole camera in 3D space. I have previously raytraced a room. As good practice I have first done the maths and the tried to program the maths in c++.

```
// Camera position
vec3 cameraPos(0, 0, -19);


// Rotate camera
float& yaw;
vec3 c1(cos(yaw), 0, sin(yaw));
vec3 c2(0, 1, 0);
vec3 c3(-sin(yaw), 0, cos(yaw));
glm::mat3 R(c1, c2, c3);
```

What I have done to rotate the camera is this:

```
if (keystate[SDLK_LEFT])
{
    //cameraPos.x -= translation;
    if (yaw > 0)
    {   
        yaw = 0.01;
    }
    cout << yaw << endl;
    cameraPos = R * cameraPos;
    cout << "LEFT" << endl;
}
if (keystate[SDLK_RIGHT])
{
    //cameraPos.x += translation;
    if (yaw > 0)
    {
        yaw = -0.01;
    }
    cout << yaw << endl;
    cameraPos = R * cameraPos;
    cout << "RIGHT" << endl;
}
```

I have multiplied the rotation matrix R with the camera position vector. What happens now is that the room moves only to the left no matter what key I press.

The tutorial I am following says:

> If the camera is rotated by the matrix R then vectors representing the
>   right (x-axis), down (y-axis) and forward (z-axis) directions van be
>   retrieved as:
>
> ```
> vec3 right(R[0][0],R[0][1],R[0][2]);
> vec3 down(R[1][0],R[1][1],R[2][2]);
> vec3 right(R[2][0],R[2][1],R[2][2]);
> ```
>
> To model a rotating camera you need to use these directions both when
>   you move the camera and when you cast rays.

I don't understand how I am supposed to use the above information.

Any help or references appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be updating your `R` matrix after changing the `yaw`. This means that every time you do `camerapos = R * camerapos` you are rotating the `camerapos` vector in one direction.

More proper way to do this would be to have the camerapos separate, build the `R` every time and use another vector for the result of the camera position.

Something like this:

```
// Camera position
vec3 cameraPos(0, 0, -19);
vec3 trueCameraPos;
float yaw;

if (keystate[SDLK_LEFT])
{
    //cameraPos.x -= translation;
    if (yaw > 0)
    {   
        yaw = 0.01;
    }
    cout << yaw << endl;
    cout << "LEFT" << endl;
}
if (keystate[SDLK_RIGHT])
{
    //cameraPos.x += translation;
    if (yaw > 0)
    {
        yaw = -0.01;
    }
    cout << yaw << endl;
    cout << "RIGHT" << endl;
}

// Rotate camera
vec3 c1(cos(yaw), 0, sin(yaw));
vec3 c2(0, 1, 0);
vec3 c3(-sin(yaw), 0, cos(yaw));
glm::mat3 R(c1, c2, c3);

trueCameraPos = R * cameraPos;
```

As for the camera definitions, the camera needs three vectors to define its orientation. If you rotate the camera the orientation also rotates, otherwise you'd just move the camera and it would always be looking in one direction.

The definition in yellow is incorrect, since there should be three perpendicular vectors, usually *up*, *right* and *forward*. Now there are two right vectors (one being *down* is just opposite of what *up* would be), so the last one should be *forward* vector.

These vectors define the directions used in the raytracer. Forward is where the rays are traced to, up and right define displacement directions in the image plane for each image pixel. You are most likely using these already in your tracing code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Concerning the yellow highlighted section do you understand what it means?

Comment: It's saying that each row of the rotation matrix corresponds with a direction vector (relative to whatever the base frame represents). So row 1 of `R` is the "right"-direction vector, etc. Compare to x-hat, y-hat, and z-hat in general physics contexts. I believe the second "right" is a typo, and was meant to say "forward".

Comment: Yeah I believe so too. Thanks :)

Comment: @Lebowski Added info about those too, user2475059 is correct about the second *right* being *forward*.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have not implemented the "right", "down", "forward" anywhere in my code. The modifications you made work, and I have a rotation. I am just not sure if it a rotation or a translation, since I am worried that the "right", "down", "forward" must be used in order to get the right perspective. I am a little confused.

Comment: @Lebowski You have some kind of vectors in the code when you loop every pixel of the resulting image and trace a ray through them. Those vectors should be these three. You might have just constants if the camera has always pointed into a single direction. You can easily test it, since if you keep rotating the camera then you either end up looking at the scene from the opposite side when reaching 180 degrees or you're constantly looking in the same direction and the camera is just rotating around the origo.

Comment: @Lebowski You may want to read up on rotation matrices. I have personally found studying rotations to be one of the more generally useful things I've done in engineering (aero), as they seem to be used a lot in a wide range of contexts.

Comment: @user2475059 I have looked at the wikipedia page. Anything else you could recommend. I would like to be good at this stuff.

Comment: @Lebowski It'll depend on your level of expertise. A course in linear algebra wouldn't hurt, if you haven't had one. I'm not having good luck finding intro pages I'd recommend; they all seem to either not say what matters or go waay off the deep end of math. [This](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/rotation_12.pdf) is one of the better hardcore math ones I found looking quickly. Honestly, a lot of it (to me) is being comfortable with the linear algebra that suffuses rotation math; once you get the context, the matrices themselves are pretty straightforward.